# HTTP Digest authentication python

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

My goal is to access a website that uses HTTP authentication using python. I can open the website from my web browser and the header tells me that I should use HTTBDigestAuth:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization: Digest username="user", realm="CG Downloads", nonce="cTN0pKxqBQA=e46ad250f42f73e9076ebc97c417f0d38bac094a", uri="/fileadmin/teaching/2017/WS/adip/exercises/adip-uebung-00-.pdf", algorithm=MD5, response="5a57ddbcd1b20444100a91b1967a2782", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="5a6b041b4113bb9a"
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: fe_typo_user=76b7e7e25372f782d94e91b51b854568
Host: cg.cs.uni-bonn.de
Referer: http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/de/lehre/ws-2017/vorlesung-algorithmisches-denken-und-imperative-programmierung/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

However when I try to go the the page using requests and HTTPDigestAuth I get "401 Unauthorized" as a response.

```
import logging
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

try:
    import httplib
except ImportError:
    import http.client as httplib

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) 

url = 'http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/teaching/2017/WS/adip/exercises/adip-uebung-00-.pdf'
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'),
                 timeout=10)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
print(r.text)
```

Am I using the wrong authorization method or is my code wrong? I appreciate any help you can give me.

**EDIT:**
I am trying to access sites on cg.cs.uni-bonn.de, for example http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/teaching/2017/WS/adip/exercises/adip-uebung-00-.pdf

Comment: can you post the url?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass values to `auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')` like this:

```
user = 'admin'    # change to your username
pass = '123456'    # change to your password
...
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(user, pass),
             timeout=10)
...
```